# C# include relationship object from many to many with automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to map from Role to RoleModel including the Feature/FeatureModel, but I haven't been able to make it work properly.

It returns the role but does not include the features:

```
{
    "name": "Backend",
    "description": "Backend role",
    "roleFeatures": [],
    "roleUsers": [],
    "updatedDate": "2023-02-03T16:14:54.036441",
    "deletedDate": null,
    "id": "82a443bd-81d3-4460-8a67-08db0601365e",
    "createdDate": "2023-02-03T16:14:54.036441",
    "deleted": false
}
```

This is the map I created:

```
 CreateMap<Role, RoleModel>()
            .ForMember(rm => rm.RoleFeatures, opt => opt
                .MapFrom(r => r.RoleFeatures.Select(y => y.Feature).ToList()))
            .MaxDepth(1);
```

These are the classes:
Role

```
public class Role : BaseRecord
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public ICollection<RoleFeature> RoleFeatures { get; set; }
   public ICollection<RoleUser> RoleUsers { get; set; }
}
```

RoleModel

```
public class RoleModel : BaseRecordModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RoleFeatureModel> RoleFeatures { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RoleUserModel> RoleUsers { get; set; }
    }
```

RoleFeature

```
  public class RoleFeature
    {
        public bool Read { get; set; }
        public bool Write { get; set; }
        public bool Edit { get; set; }
        public bool Delete { get; set; }
        public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
        public Guid FeatureId { get; set; }
        public Feature Feature { get; set; }
    }
```

RoleFeatureModel

```
 public class RoleFeatureModel
    {
        public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
        public Guid FeatureId { get; set; }
        public bool Read { get; set; }
        public bool Write { get; set; }
        public bool Edit { get; set; }
        public bool Delete { get; set; }
        public RoleModel Role { get; set; }
        public FeatureModel Feature { get; set; }
    }
```

Previously I was creating a simple map:

```
 CreateMap<Role, RoleModel>();
```

But I was getting an object cycle error, now I get the roleModel but the roleFeature list is empty.

Comment: Because you are using `MaxDepth(1)` so it will map to a depth of 1.. which explains why your reference arrays are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm gonna listen to what my guts tell me - you are querying for the roles in **lazy loading** manner (default), aren't you?

You have to include related members explicitly, for example:

```
var resultSet = await _context.Roles.Include(r => r.RoleFeatures).ToListAsync();
```

`Include()` method enforces so called **eager loading**, providing you not only with requested data, but also its related members.

It also can be chained e.g.:

```
var resultSet = _context.Roles.Include(r => r.RoleFeatures)
                              .Include(r => r.RoleUsers)
                                  .ToListAsync();
```

**OR**

If you are already using eager loading.

Instead of constraining your mapper with `MaxDepth(1)`, go to your `ConfigureServices()` (in your `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs`) method, and configure JsonSerializer in a way that suits you the best, for example:

```
services.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;
    options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
});
```

Above example uses `Newtonsoft.Json`, but you can achieve the same effect reffering ReferenceLoopHandling with `System.Text.Json` serializer.